# How to group by value from different tags?

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I have a XML like the following:

```
<DataSet>
 <FirstNode>
  <UniqueKey>111</UniqueKey>
 </FirstNode>
 <FirstNode>
  <UniqueKey>123</UniqueKey>
 </FirstNode>
 <FirstNode>
  <UniqueKey>144</UniqueKey>
 </FirstNode>
 <SecondNode>
  <FirstNodeKey>111</FirstNodeKey>
 </SecondNode>
 <SecondNode>
  <FirstNodeKey>123</FirstNodeKey>
 </SecondNode>
 <SecondNode>
  <FirstNodeKey>144</FirstNodeKey>
 </SecondNode>
</DataSet>
```

I want to use XSLT to get:

```
<DataSet>
     <FirstNode>
      <UniqueKey>111</UniqueKey>
     </FirstNode>
     <SecondNode>
      <FirstNodeKey>111</FirstNodeKey>
     </SecondNode>
</DataSet>
<DataSet>
     <FirstNode>
      <UniqueKey>123</UniqueKey>
     </FirstNode>
     <SecondNode>
      <FirstNodeKey>123</FirstNodeKey>
     </SecondNode>
</DataSet>
<DataSet>
     <FirstNode>
      <UniqueKey>144</UniqueKey>
     </FirstNode>
     <SecondNode>
      <FirstNodeKey>144</FirstNodeKey>
     </SecondNode>
</DataSet>
```

If the tag is the same, I can use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="DataSet">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="UniqueKey">
          <Updates>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </Updates>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I do this when the tags are different? How can I group on these two different tags? (UniqueKey and FirstNodeKey for my case).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is no element having both of these key elements you can simply use `group-by="UniqueKey, FirstNodeKey"` as that forms the sequence of the two elements which, in your case, will simply be a sequence with either `UniqueKey` or `FirstNodeKey`, as the other selection is empty.

Comment: Thanks! But now I have another use-case. Now what if I want to group <FirstNode> by a tag that only exists in <FirstNode> and then group <FirstNode> and <SecondNode>? For example <FirstNode><UniqueKey>111</UniqueKey> <OtherKey>552</OtherKey></FirstNode>... the result would be like <FirstNode><UniqueKey>111</UniqueKey> <OtherKey>552</OtherKey></FirstNode><FirstNode><UniqueKey>123</UniqueKey> <OtherKey>552</OtherKey></FirstNode>

Comment: Please ask a new question with properly formatted samples of input, desired output, code you have tried and output you currently get. It doesn't make much sense asking us to understand new requirements from code posted in comments.

Comment: Martin, I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121756/xslt-do-a-group-by-twice-first-within-the-same-tag-and-then-by-2-different-ta Thanks a lot for your help!